# HTML/PHP Storing values in table, saving to database and showing it later

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am new and trying to make a simple website for a project. I have to pages, add and view hobbies. User needs to be able to add 1 or more hobbies and store it in a database and to retrieve it in another page, i have listed what i plan to do below.

***How do i make it such that I am able to store multiple hobbies for users in the database?***

Using MySQL, HTML, PHP, Dreamweaver

Assume: User has been created, user has been logged in and all user related database coding has been done. More than 1 user exists, all users are to have a few hobbies each.

**Database**
User table: UserId, Username, HobbyId
Hobby table: HobbyId, HobbyName, HobbyDaysAWeek

1 user can have 0 or more Hobbies.

**Add hobby page**

- dropdownlist (binds list of hobbies from hobby table)
- textbox (for user to enter how many days a week he spends engaging in that hobby)
- add button (displays value in dropdownlist and textbox in a table)
- table (Hobby and daysAWeek will be shown here, with a delete icon to delete it)
- submit button(saves hobby & days a week & username into database)

**View hobby page**

- Displays user's hobby & days a week in a table.

Thanks for helping! And please provide simple and bare minimum coding as i am new!

Comment: start by adding a 3rd table with UserId and HobbyId

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that if i have 100 users with 4 hobbies each, i will have 400 entries in the table? That's gonna make it really big..

Comment: You're storing *the* relationship between, not *a* relationship. So think of it like you have two things and you want to remember that they relate. Thus, a table with two columns, one with an identifier of one part, the other with identifier (ID) of the other part. Pull them together with the data about each part, you have information. Hence, you've stored *the* relationship. It's like metadata, really. It's usually pretty efficient.

Comment: 400 is not big, 400 million is, db are designed for this

Comment: @Theone: No - you will have up to 400 entries in the table. You will have 400 if everybody has all hobbies, or 0 if they're all lazy bastards.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for explaining it to me, I understand what to do now!

Comment: or else you can add userId as foreign key in hobbies table. You need not go for third table.

Comment: @Chella - That would entirely relate to how the data needed to be modeled. It could very flat, hobbies duplicated all over the place; or, you could separate hobbies and just reference the relationship.

Comment: @Jared: yes you are right..! Thanks. I thought hobbies would be distinct for each user. But I dint thought that the same hobbies would be repeated for many. any way thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody posted an answer but my question was answered in the comments so..

Start by adding a 3rd table with UserId and HobbyId – Dagon

You're storing the relationship between, not a relationship. So think of it like you have two things and you want to remember that they relate. Thus, a table with two columns, one with an identifier of one part, the other with identifier (ID) of the other part. Pull them together with the data about each part, you have information. Hence, you've stored the relationship. It's like metadata, really. It's usually pretty efficient. - Jared Farrish

Thanks guys!

Comment: I've always referred to these as "lookup tables" but some folks don't. I've also heard them called junction tables. if you ever get into database normalization, you start to get into some pretty odd situations with these types of tables (for instance, check out the Drupal database schema diagrams sometime).